# I have MultipleSeletion Dropdown I want to deselect sleceted values of the dropdown do not Know how to do this

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dropdown

Now I am using this code to unselect the selected values of dropdown but its not working

```
var Diag = document.getElementById('<%=selDiag.ClientID%>');
var diag1 = "";
var diag2 = "";
var diag3 = "";
var diag4 = "";

var options = Diag.getElementsByTagName('option');
for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    options[i].selected == false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`'=='` is a comparison operation, you need to use `'='`

```js
var Diag = document.getElementById('tst');

var options = Diag.getElementsByTagName('option');
for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
    options[i].selected = false;
}
```

```html
 <select id="tst" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: var Diag = document.getElementById('<%=selDiag.ClientID%>').selectedOptions;
              
             
                var options = Diag.getElementsByTagName('option');
                for (var i = 0, len = Diag.length; i < len; i++) {
                    Diag[i].selected = false;
                    
                }

Comment: @user3809514 You need to replace Diag.length with options.length and Diag[i] with options[i], The code I put is working , just copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

set the value="" or "0" for item you want as default selected item..
here is an example..

```
<select id="To_Year" class="form-control" style="color: black; height: 36px; margin: 4px; text-align: center;">
                <%Response.Write("<option value=''>To Year</option>");

                  for (Int32 cnt = 2000; cnt <= (DateTime.Now.Year) + 5; cnt++)
                  {
                      Response.Write("<option value='" + cnt + "'>" + cnt + "</option>");
                  }

                %>
            </select>
```

And simply call them in you script as following..

```
$("#To_Year").val("");
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('<%=To_Year.ClientID%>').val("");
```